# Bing returns garbed text for PDFs

Tags: bing, pdf

Bing Search results that include this PDF...

http://www.uawtrust.org/AdminCenter/Library.Files/Media/501/HealthWellness/Docs/Prevention/depression.pdf

Look like this (wrong title - "Deei" instead of "Depression", gibberish instead of saying "Permafold")....
[image: Deei]

Search results that include this PDF

http://www.uawtrust.org/AdminCenter/Library.Files/Media/501/HealthWellness/Docs/Prevention/osteoporosis.pdf

Look like this (complete nonsense for the title)

[image]

The results look fine in Google, and the documents look fine in Adobe Reader, as well as Chrome and Firefox's native viewers.  Why is this happening and is there anything we can do about it?

Here's the bing search: https://www.bing.com/search?q=%22is%20not%20meant%20to%20take%20the%20place%22%20site%3Auawtrust.org&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%22is%20not%20meant%20to%20take%20the%20place%22%20site%3Auawtrust.org&sc=0-50&sk=&cvid=E3473DA56AA0471B8257EE59BB1A115C

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have not optimised the PDF for search engines as there is no meta information on the document. I have added a screenshot of what search engines will be seeing.

This can be updated with most PDF readers.

[image]

If you want to make sure the whole document is SEO optimised, I would recommend this article by MOZ. [How to Optimize PDF Documents for Search](https://moz.com/ugc/how-to-optimize-pdf-documents-for-search)

**Checklist for PDF Optimization:**

1. Search-friendly filenames
2. Keyword-optimized titles
3. Informative, concise descriptions
4. Company name in "Author" field
5. Use several relevant keywords in "Keyword" field
6. Make sure to fill out all available fields - there is an option to view "Additional Metadata" (in Adobe Acrobat)
7. Add tags to and accessibility options to your
   document
8. Don't forget about Alt tags for images
9. Add links back to relevant pages on the main website Write-protect the document
10. Offer HTML version of the document

https://moz.com/ugc/how-to-optimize-pdf-documents-for-search

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, and I'll have our content people do that...  although it won't help with Bing garbling the the text in the text snippet :-(